# Alignment issues when assigning the result of a sbrk to a pointer - K&R

Tags: c, malloc, memory-alignment, kernighan-and-ritchie, sbrk

referencing this code from Kernighan and Ritchie (2nd edition page 188),

```
static Header* morecore(unsigned nu) {
    char *cp, *sbrk(int);
    Header* up;

    if (nu < NALLOC) 
        nu = NALLOC;

    cp = sbrk(nu * sizeof(Header));

    if (cp == (char*) -1) /* No space at all */
        return NULL;

    up = (Header*) cp;
    up->s.size = nu;
    free((void*)(up+1));
    return freep;
}
```

The question here is what happens when the value returned by `sbrk` is something like 101, the alignment will be invalid when the pointer assignment to `up` is done in the line `up = (Header*)cp;`

This might have a really obvious answer so sorry if I missed it!

Comment: What happens is undefined. In practice that might mean the program works as expected, it works as expected but slower, or it crashes with an alignment fault.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/brk.html), the authoritiveness of which I cannot say:

> It is unspecified whether the pointer returned by sbrk() is aligned suitably for any purpose.

So basically, yes, you may very well find there are alignment issues.

Comment: @Curious It not really a bug because it's not supposed to be conforming to the Singual Unix Specification. It's an example of code that might be used in the implementation of a C library, and as such it also doesn't conform to the C standard either, as it defines functions named `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: @RossRidge if the code is not conforming to any specification then it should probably assert that the value returned by the function is aligned on the right boundary?

Comment: @Curious The book actually does mention that: "The use of `typedef` and `union` handles alignment (given that `sbrk` supplies an appropriate pointer)."  The book admits that memory allocation is intrinsically machine-dependent and the code only tries to limit those dependencies not eliminate them completely.

Comment: @RossRidge hmmm, so in reality if making a library for malloc you should always align such a pointer to the right boundary right?

Comment: @Curious In reality you may not need to because in reality the `sbrk` implementation used always returns suitably aligned memory. Given how `sbrk` is defined and typically implemented this may in fact be true of most or even all `sbrk` implementations. It was almost certainly true at the time the book was written.

Comment: @RossRidge You're making an assertion which directly contravenes the SUSv2 cited in the answer. It would have been trivial for K&R to increase/align the value of `cp` to a multiple of `sizeof(Align)` before casting to `Header *`, plus the whole point of section 8.7 is to demonstrate machine-independent coding practices. In this context, the quoted phrase "given that `sbrk` supplies an appropriate pointer" sounds to me like an admission of an omission/oversight on their part.